# Is there any reason why my filter-mapping doesn't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, web.xml, url-pattern

when I declare a filter mapping like that :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It works when I browse `http://localhost:8080/myApp/pages/test.action`

But if I declare it like that :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It doesn't works and I verified that my context path is `myApp`

My application is deployed on JBOSS 5.1

I hope someone could tell my what's wrong
Thanks in advance

EDIT : 
All my filter-mapping :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestInfo</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>   
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: What app server or servlet container are you talking about?

Comment: My application is deployed on JBOSS 5.1

Comment: There are other filters declared on web.xml?

Comment: Yes, there are others.
but none with /pages/* pattern

Comment: Can you paste the other filters.

Comment: It's better to see entire web.xml

Comment: I edited and posted all my filter-mapping

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I use filter for /* and then add excludes for the pages I don't want filtered.

Answer (score 0):

If you give anything in url-mapping, it tries to map for that mapping itself, rather than trying to figure out your entered URL.

Try :

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/pages/pages/test.action`

If this works then you will have to change your action mapping in the struts configuration file.